# How to convert string value to decimal

Tags: c#, .net

There is a string values

```
1. 28000 Million
2. 15592 Million
```

1.
Now I am converting these values as

```
decimal val=Convert.ToDecimal(28000)/1000//To convert it into billion.
Here val=28
return val.Tostring("F1");///Gives 28.0
```

2.

```
decimal val=Convert.ToDecimal(15592)/1000//To convert it into billion.
Here val=15.592
return val.Tostring("F1");///Gives 15.6
```

Now What I want here instead of 28.0 I want 28
15.6 is fine for me.

How can I ignore decimal in case of 28.0?

Comment: You just need to format it correctly.  See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Format it with `"F0"` instead of `"F1"`?  You're explicitly specifying the formatter.  To use a different format, use a different formatter.  Note that this has nothing to do with the string from which you evaluated the decimal.  The only relevant line of code here is `val.ToString("F1")`.

Comment: you want to convert String to Decimal or Decimal to String ? Correct your title !

Answer (score 1):

```
        var val =Convert.ToDecimal(28000) / 1000;
        Console.WriteLine(val.ToString("N")); // 28,00
        Console.WriteLine(val.ToString("F0"));  // 28
        Console.WriteLine(val.ToString("F1"));   //28,0
```

EDIT:

```
        var val =Convert.ToDecimal(15592) / 1000;
        Console.WriteLine(val.ToString("N")); // 15,59
        Console.WriteLine(val.ToString("F0"));  // 16
        Console.WriteLine(val.ToString("F1"));   //15,6
```

Comment: Work... somehow. Point for U. Correct is 'val.Tostring("N");'

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
return val.Tostring();
```

Maybe this is what you want. This is without a Limitation of decimal places

Answer (score 0):

you should try parsing to integer

```
 decimal val=Convert.ToDecimal(28000)/1000//To convert it into billion.
 Here val=28
 int i = 0;
 Int32.TryParse(val.ToString(), out i);

  return i ==0?  return val.Tostring("F1") :  return i.Tostring();
```